# User profiles - some use listform.aspx, others userdisp.aspx

Tags: 2010, user-profile

On a SharePoint 2010 installation we have a small number of users whose user profile URLs (i.e. click on their name in the list of users) goes to something like this:

https://sharepoint.org/_Layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={05775869-AC0D-4C49-AC4F-2AC3374A52F4}&ID=168

These always result in a 'Page not found' error.

All other users, however, go to:

https://sharepoint.org/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=108

which works just fine.

Two questions:

1) Why is there a difference? As far as I can tell the users have been created in the same manner.

2) How does one sort out the Page not found error, other than enabling My Sites (which I don't want to do)?

Comment: I believe I've come across this before, and the fix I did was to recreate the User Profile Service App, because there is no way to "undo" the MySites once you've tampered with them. Basically once you configure MySites, it will redirect the user links to their respective mysite.